# Javascript URI decode not performing as expected

Tags: javascript, uri, urldecode

I am using the following javascript method to decode a URL.

```
decodeURIComponent();
```

When entering the encoded version in the browser it shows the expected image. Following the use of the above decode function, the new URL does not display the image.

How can I decode this properly?

The URL is:

Encoded:

"https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB9-zMODCId1OZa&w=128&h=128&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhprofile-xpa1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-1%2Fp200x200%2F12289537_1025015047521253_6948708859100232371_n.png%3Foh%3Dd4b09489497f8705ca75467bd6af54e9%26oe%3D578DF677&upscale=1&ext=jpg”

Decoded:

"https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB9-zMODCId1OZa&w=128&h=128&url=https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12289537_1025015047521253_6948708859100232371_n.png?oh=d4b09489497f8705ca75467bd6af54e9&oe=578DF677&upscale=1&ext=jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decodeURIComponent()` function isn't decoding your URI the way you expect because it's really only intended to work with strings that were previously encoded with `encodeURIComponent()`.

Instead, you want to use [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

```js
var url = 'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB9-zMODCId1OZa&w=128&h=128&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhprofile-xpa1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-1%2Fp200x200%2F12289537_1025015047521253_6948708859100232371_n.png%3Foh%3Dd4b09489497f8705ca75467bd6af54e9%26oe%3D578DF677&upscale=1&ext=jpg';
var decoded = decodeURI(url);
document.write(decoded);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help